# How to make combination based on other column in Panda dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, python-itertools

I have a dataframe with keywords column. Keywords column has also 2-7 keywords which are separated by comma. For example:

```
URL                                    Keywords
www.example.com                   "Keyword 1 , Keyword 2 , Keyword 3"
www.example2.com                  "Keyword 2, Keyword 4, Keyword 5"
.
.
.
```

i want the output which generate combinations but only two. I need actually values for "TO" and "FROM" for visualization. I expect the output in this way

```
URL                      Keyword Combination
www.example.com          Keyword 1, Keyword 2
www.example.com          Keyword 1, Keyword 3
www.example.com          Keyword 2, Keyword 1
www.example.com          Keyword 2, Keyword 3
.
.
.
.
```

I think it will be possible with **ITERTOOLS** but i am not sure how i can implement on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`itertools.permutation`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations), [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain), and [`df.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) (for pandas >= 0.25.0):

```
>>> lst = [[','.join(p) for p in permutations(val.split(','),2)] for val in df['Keywords']]
>>> df['Keywords'] = lst
>>> df.explode('Keywords')

  URL                                                    Keywords
0      www.example.com                     Keyword 1 , Keyword 2 
0      www.example.com                      Keyword 1 , Keyword 3
0      www.example.com                      Keyword 2 ,Keyword 1 
0      www.example.com                      Keyword 2 , Keyword 3
0      www.example.com                       Keyword 3,Keyword 1 
0      www.example.com                      Keyword 3, Keyword 2 
1      www.example2.com                      Keyword 2, Keyword 4
1      www.example2.com                      Keyword 2, Keyword 5
1      www.example2.com                       Keyword 4,Keyword 2
1      www.example2.com                      Keyword 4, Keyword 5
1      www.example2.com                       Keyword 5,Keyword 2
1      www.example2.com                      Keyword 5, Keyword 4
```